# It is possible to use different PHP versions in lampp

Tags: php, linux, lampp, manjaro

I am using linux manjaro with the local lampp server, however the version of my php is 7.2 but I want to use the 5.6 to do some tests, my question is is it possible for me to do this procedure using the lampp?

Comment: Im not sure if it is possible. Personally, I did not find solution for this, so I've two different servers and switching between them if I need to test something on different php version.

Comment: Certainly it is possible to install (and use) several versions of php in parallel. You may only configure one version as that to be used in an http servers php module, but that is the only typical limitation. You can setup other runners or use php from the command line, for example `fastCGI`. That way you _can_ provide separate version for a single http server. You _do_ have to take care to call the _correct_ version, however ;-) All you need to do is use your distriutions software management system to install the versions (packages) you want.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.